# SonataAdminBundle redirect / (homepage) to /admin/dashboard

Tags: symfony, redirect, fosuserbundle, sonata-admin

I'm using SonataAdminBundle and I want my secured area to be under `/admin`, and I want to have a homepage on `/` that is a list of objects.

But when I go on `/` I'm automatically redirected to `/admin/dashboard`.
This works fine if my "homepage" is under another url (e.g : `/homepage`)

Here is my `config.yml`:

```
sonata_admin:
    title: 'Versus'
    title_logo: 'logo_title.png'
    templates:
        # other configuration options
        search:              '@SonataAdmin/Core/search.html.twig'
        search_result_block: 'template/Admin/Search/block_search_result.html.twig'
        edit:                'template/Admin/CRUD/edit.html.twig'
    global_search:
        empty_boxes: fade

sonata_block:
    blocks:
        # enable the SonataAdminBundle block
        sonata.admin.block.admin_list:
            contexts: [admin]
        sonata.admin.block.search_result:
            contexts: [admin]

fos_user:
    db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb' and 'couchdb'
    firewall_name: admin
    user_class: AppBundle\Entity\User
    from_email:
        address: "%mailer_user%"
        sender_name: "%mailer_user%"
```

Here is my `security.yml` :

```
firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
                # if you are using Symfony < 2.8, use the following config instead:
                # csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true
        # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
```

And here is my `routing.yml` :

```
admin_area:
    resource: '@SonataAdminBundle/Resources/config/routing/sonata_admin.xml'
    prefix: /admin

_sonata_admin:
    resource: .
    type: sonata_admin
    prefix: /admin

fos_user:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/all.xml"

front:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/*"
    type: annotation
    prefix: /
```

I don't know what is causing the redirection, and how I can prevent it.

Comment: Tried to remove prefix from front route? It's not needed. Why is there no ressource path for sonata admin?

Comment: I tried to remove the prefix from front route, but I still have the redirection. About the resource path, I followed the instructions on the official sonata documentation : https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/3-x/doc/getting_started/installation.html#define-routes

Comment: For information, it has something to do with the web browser. Maybe cookies… If I open `/` in private mode, or in chrome, it works as expected…